# What are the block heights of the different eras of cardano?

Tags: shelley, byron

According to the [roadmap](https://roadmap.cardano.org/en/) Cardano has (or will have) five eras. Byron, Shelley, Goguen, Basho and Voltaire. What block height did Cardano change from one era to the next?

Answer (score 5):

This is the best resource I've found online.

[image: Era Boundaries]

[Source](https://cardanosolutions.github.io/kupo/#section/Era-Boundaries)

Answer (score 3):

Byron (Genesis) (09/27/2017) - Epoch 1, Block 1?

Shelley (07/29/2020) - Epoch 208, Block 4490511

Goguen (if you consider Alonzo HFC the start of Goguen) (09/12/2021) - Epoch 290, Block 6236060

Basho and Voltaire are currently in development.

Important to note: the Cardano eras are rough pictures of where development is focused during that era, not hard dates. Parts of Shelley and Goguen are still being worked (decentralization parameters and smart contract optimizations, respectively). It is not clear cut whether something like the integrations of CIP 31, 32, and 33 should be considered part of Goguen or Basho. Also, project Catalyst is technically part of Voltaire and has been around for over a year at this point.

Comment: Is there a website you got the data from? I am asking so that I can look it up when the next era rolls out.

Comment: No, tbh I just remembered 

Comment: damn that's a good memory

Answer (score 0):

On mainnet:

- Byron started at epoch 0.
- Shelley started at epoch 208.

Hopefully someone else can fill in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`/network/eras` Blockfrost endpoint](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Network/paths/%7E1network%7E1eras/get).