# What block height was the vasil hardfork?

Tags: vasil-hard-fork, shelley, alonzo, byron

Additionally, did vasil correlate to a [change of era](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/what-are-the-block-heights-of-the-different-eras-of-cardano) for cardano?

Answer (score 2):

The first block appears to be at slot *83548800* according to the [`/network/eras` Blockfrost endpoint](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Network/paths/%7E1network%7E1eras/get).

```
  {
    "start": {
      "time": 157680000,
      "slot": 72316800,
      "epoch": 365
    },
    "end": {
      "time": 168912000,
      "slot": 83548800,
      "epoch": 391
    },
    "parameters": {
      "epoch_length": 432000,
      "slot_length": 1,
      "safe_zone": 129600
    }
```

Yes, Vasil has been an era change from Alonzo to Babbage.